# How to locate the Entry Points of a Drupal 8 Core module?

Tags: 8, security

I'm to perform a security audit on the Drupal 8 Core modules, and was curious if there were any telltale signs of Entry Points (ie, how a module communicates with an external module and vice-versa).

OWASP defines an Entry Point as ["the interfaces through which potential attackers can interact with the application or supply it with data."](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Application_Threat_Modeling#Entry_Points)

I assume this is not very different from Entry Points of standard web applications (forms, HTTP packets, etc.), but I am interested in knowing whether or not Drupal has its own standard as to where these Entry Points are located. Are there specific snippets of code I should be looking for?

I do intend on reviewing the modules manually and in-depth, but figured someone on here may have some advice to help lessen the steep learning curve.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Cheers! :)

Comment: Not meant as an attack in any way, but I'm not sure why you would need to do a full security audit yourself. That seems like a task that a) is going to take a huge amount of time and b) would require to be done by someone who is very experienced in Drupal to be meaningful. Drupal has a security team, all new code especially in Drupal Core is extensively reviewed and any issues that are found (which does happen from time to time) are handled responsibly. See https://www.drupal.org/drupal-security-team/general-information and the other pages there

Comment: See also https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/security/writing-secure-code-for-drupal-8 and https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/security/writing-secure-code/overview

Comment: @Berdir I appreciate the feedback, but Drupal's Security Team does not seem to review Core unless there is a reason to do so (ie someone reports a vulnerability). From the link in your first comment:

"Members of the security team sometimes perform analysis of core or contributed project code, especially if there is a weakness that can be found by easy scanning, but in general, the team does not review core nor contributed code."

Thank you for your help, though! :)

Comment: Yes, most code is maybe not specifically reviewed by the security team, but every single line that is added to Drupal core *is* reviewed, usually by several developers, and quite a few of those are on the security team. According to https://insight.sensiolabs.com/projects/4d81cdef-16cb-435e-a091-3101dfdb3c37/analyses/27, we're talking about 180k lines of code, it would take years for a single person to review that all. (Note that the critical security issues found there are false positivies)

Answer (score 2):

Entry points will equate to routes in Drupal.

Modules will normally define their routes in a YML file named MODULE_NAME.routing.yml, but routes can be defined programmatically as well, check out this article from Acquia about routes: 
 https://dev.acquia.com/blog/coding-drupal-8/defining-and-altering-routes-in-drupal-8/22/03/2016/9891

Also the 'routing' table in the database lists all the paths and their corresponding routes (I believe all).  Note the use of '%' and '{some_value}' to indicate dynamic route values.

Hope that gets you started.